# Python - QTableWidget.selectedRanges() return multiple ranges for on selection

Tags: python, qt, multiple-columns, qtablewidget

I'm new in python and develop a GUI with a table. It should be possible to connect rows and column via a context menu. And this works. 
I can selected multiple rows by using ctrl + mouse left click.

But is one or more span is/are in the table and i want to add more, QTableWidget.selectedRanges() returns **n*m** selectionRanges if if select a nXm selection.
For example if i selected 3 rows in a column, there are 3 selectionRanges.

And on the console is written 3 times

```
QTableView::setSpan: single cell span won't be added
```

Python 2.7.5+ is installed.

Thx and bye.

**Edited on 17th March 2014**

Here is the complete code of my small program.

The program.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from tableGui import Ui_Dialog as Dlg


class MarkDownTableGui(QtGui.QDialog,Dlg):
  def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)
    ColumnCount = None
    ColumnRow = None    
    # Context menu connect cell/reset connected/selected cells
    self.menu = QtGui.QMenu()           
    self.menu.addAction("Connect",self.addSpan)
    self.menu.addAction("Reset",self.resetConnected)     

    self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)

    self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showContextMenu)            
    self.connect(self.generateButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.onGenerate)

  def onGenerate(self):    
    """
      Generate a m x n table
    """
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.RowCount.value())
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(self.ColumnCount.value())

  def addSpan(self):    
    selectedElements = self.tableWidget.selectedRanges()       

    for slrange in selectedElements:      
      self.tableWidget.setSpan(slrange.topRow(),slrange.leftColumn(),slrange.rowCount(),slrange.columnCount())  


  def showContextMenu(self,pos):             
    self.menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())    

  def resetConnected(self):
    #TODO
    print "TODO"


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = MarkDownTableGui()
dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this is the tableGui.py, generated by pyuic4

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'dialog_Table.ui'
#
# Created: Mon Mar 17 08:59:43 2014
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        Dialog.resize(509, 426)
        Dialog.setModal(True)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 370, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))
        self.ColumnCount = QtGui.QSpinBox(Dialog)
        self.ColumnCount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 51, 23))
        self.ColumnCount.setMinimum(1)
        self.ColumnCount.setProperty("value", 5)
        self.ColumnCount.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ColumnCount"))
        self.labelChapterCount = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelChapterCount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 74, 23))
        self.labelChapterCount.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelChapterCount"))
        self.RowCount = QtGui.QSpinBox(Dialog)
        self.RowCount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 10, 51, 23))
        self.RowCount.setMinimum(1)
        self.RowCount.setProperty("value", 5)
        self.RowCount.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("RowCount"))
        self.labelChapterCount_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelChapterCount_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 10, 74, 23))
        self.labelChapterCount_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelChapterCount_2"))
        self.generateButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.generateButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 10, 111, 24))
        self.generateButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("generateButton"))
        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(Dialog)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 491, 321))
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), Dialog.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Table editor", None))
        self.labelChapterCount.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Column", None))
        self.labelChapterCount_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Rows", None))
        self.generateButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "generate Table", None))
```

**The problem**

1. if the programm is running you can select cell by pressing and holding the left mouse button
2. Left click open the context menu
3. Select connect, create a column/row span
4. if i want to add additional spans and start at point 1. again then i got the message

   QTableView::setSpan: single cell span won't be added

The Question is why selectedRanges() returns a list with *n* selectionRanges instead of only on selectionRange. I've read the documentation of [QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qtablewidget.html) and [QTableSelectionRange](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qtablewidgetselectionrange.html). But haven't any ideas

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? It is hard to tell what the problem is, or what you are asking for, from the information you've provided so far.

Comment: I've edited my initial post. I hope it improves the understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that spanning cells in a table changes how the selection model constructs its selection-ranges. I don't exactly know why that is, but even if this didn't happen, it would not eliminate all the problems.

By default, a table-widget allows multiple selections, so you can end up with a selection that cannot be spanned (as a whole). But even if the multiple selections were next to each other and formed a block that *could* be spanned, the selection-model will *always* record these as a list of selection-ranges, rather than merging them all into a single selection.

So to get this to work properly, I think you will have to switch to a different selection-mode before allowing a span to be set. The best option would seem to be this:

```
    self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(
        QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection)
```

which only allows single, rectangular blocks to be selected. Probably you will need a button to switch between the different selection-modes, and disable the "Connect" menu-item as appropriate.

This still leaves the problem of dealing with the list of selection-ranges after the first span has been set. To fix that, you can do the following:

```
    def addSpan(self): 
        selection = list(self.tableWidget.selectionModel().selection())
        selection.sort()
        top = selection[0].top()
        left = selection[0].left()
        bottom = selection[-1].bottom()
        right = selection[-1].right()
        self.tableWidget.setSpan(
            top, left, bottom - top + 1, right - left + 1)
```

I'm not sure whether sorting the selection is actually necessary, but it does  guarantee that the selection-ranges are always in the right order.